# Subscript out of range when attempting to access array

Tags: excel, vba

Why do I get a "Subscript out of range" error when trying to access my array in this macro? Looping through the array using something like `for each v in a then debug.print v` works fine, but when trying to access it using the index, I get the error shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

The macro itself looks like this, and the line throwing the error is `If DateValue(a(i)) = DateValue(t) Then`

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 0

Sub gå_til_flik()
    Dim t As Date
    Dim a() As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    
    t = Now

    a = Plan_Å1_endeleg.Range("B3:B" & Plan_Å1_endeleg.Range("B" & Plan_Å1_endeleg.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    
    For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
        If DateValue(a(i)) = DateValue(t) Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Change `a(i)` with `a(i, 1)`. Such an array is a 2D type... It needs row and column.

Comment: Lol, of course it was something as simple as that - I can't believe I didn't think of that myself! Thanks a lot for the help, @FaneDuru.

Comment: Glad I could help...

Comment: Do not despair.  You have encountered one of the more heinous practises of Excel.  Consider the fact that you requested a 1 dimensional array from Excel.  What you got was a 1 dimensional array in 2d format.  That's not helpful in the least.